# Looking for help with WiFi modules

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I'm completely new to using modules for the Arduino, so I'm sure some people have more knowledge about this topic than me.
Here's the thing, I want to stream audio over my home wifi, so I'm in need of some rather high-speed modules, I'm aiming for 1-1.5 mbps for some proper compressed audio, including the overhead.

I've looked online for some well known wifi modules, but the only one I've managed to find that is popular is the esp8266, and that thing is definitely not for streaming anything.

Before anyone asks, yes, it is critical for it to work over wifi.
Has anyone done something like this? What gets the best results?

Comment: I think the uno will already be a bottleneck here.

Comment: The audio issue aside look at the Adafruit Huzzah ESP8266 breakout. It is a really great board, and you can run your Arduino code directly on it, removing the need to fight AT commands and all that.  It is also really cheep, compared to an Arduino and a WiFi shield.  For audio though, i would look at a microcomputer (Raspberry Pi maybe?) instead of a micro controller.

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment so I'm going to post as an answer.  Arduino is most likely not capable of running any sort of audio unless you have an mp3 shield to support it.  As far as the wifi module, I suggest using Ethernet shield as that will run a lot better compared to wifi module.